# Problem with nested FindRoot definition

Tags: equation-solving

I'm using a thermistor to measure temperature, and have defined a function using datasheet function which gives temperature as a function of measured resistance.

```
Recip610[R_] := 
 0.0011279 + (2.3429 Log[R])/10^4 + (8.7298 Log[R]^3)/10^8 (* This is the datasheet function, which gives the reciprocal of absolute temperature *)

temp[R_] := 1/Recip610[R] - 273.15 (* This gives temp in degrees C *)
```

`FindRoot` can easily numerically solve this, finding a resistance for any given temperature.

```
r610[T_] := Values[FindRoot[temp[R] == T, {R, 10000}]][[1]]  (* This function works. *)
```

Next, I am using the thermistor in a resistive voltage divider circuit, and measuring the voltage across the thermistor.  The equation for the voltage divider is similarly straightforward.  I define a function for this voltage, and it evaluates to a temperature.

```
v610[T_] := (5 r610[T])/(200000 + r610[T])
```

I can even plot this function. But when I try to use `FindRoot` a second time to give me the temperature for any given measured value of the voltage, I get a list of errors:

```
FindRoot[v610[T] - .3, {T, 20}]
```

> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {25.0016 -1. T} is not a list of
> numbers with dimensions {1} at {R} = {10000.}.
>
> Values::invrl: The argument FindRoot[temp[R]==T,{R,10000}] is not a
> valid Association or a list of rules.
>
> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {25.0016 -1. T} is not a list of
> numbers with dimensions {1} at {R} = {10000.}.
>
> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {25.0016 -1. T} is not a list of
> numbers with dimensions {1} at {R} = {10000.}.
>
> General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nlnum will be suppressed
> during this calculation.
>
> Values::invrl: The argument FindRoot[temp[R]==T,{R,10000}] is not a
> valid Association or a list of rules.

This puzzles me, because the function `v610[T]`, as defined above, evaluates correctly.  Yet when I ask `FindRoot` to find what `T` evaluates to, say, 0.3, it fails.  (But, by trial and error, I found that `v610[19.5231]` evaluates to 0.3.)

Why does `FindRoot` fail to give a solution, when the function I am asking it find the root of both evaluates correctly and even plots correctly?

[image: Here is a plot of v610[T], evaluated as T goes from 0 to 50 degrees C. Over that temperature range, the voltage drops from about 0.7 V down to just over 0.1 V.]

```
Plot[v610[T], {T, 0, 50}]
```

I'd appreciate two different answers to this question: first, what is code that will work?  (voltage in, temperature out, for the circuit and the thermistor function that I have).  Second, I'd like to understand the specific reason that `FindRoot` is not able to find a solution when the function I'm asking it to solve appears to be well-behaved, i.e. it evaluates normally and can be plotted.  Is the problem that `FindRoot` can't be nested?

```
v610[T_] := 5*(r610[T]/(200000 + r610[T])) 
r610[T_] := Values[FindRoot[temp[R] == T, {R, 10000}]][[1]] 
temp[R_] := 1/Recip610[R] - 273.15 
Recip610[R_] := 0.0011279 + (2.3429*Log[R])/10^4 + 
(8.7298*Log[R]^3)/10^8
v610[T_] := 5*(r610[T]/(200000 + r610[T])) 
r610[T_] := Values[FindRoot[temp[R] == T, {R, 10000}]][[1]] 
temp[R_] := 1/Recip610[R] - 273.15 
Recip610[R_] := 0.0011279 + (2.3429*Log[R])/10^4 + 
(8.7298*Log[R]^3)/10^8
```

(Edited to add code window)

Comment: Hi! You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: First, `r610[20]` does not return a number (it returns a list), which you probably want to do. (?)  Second, you probably need [`?NumericQ`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037): `ClearAll[v610]; v610[T_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: Maybe for `r610[T_?NumericQ] := ..` too

Comment: I included Values[ ... ][[1]] in the definition of r610 to pick out the first item of the list, so what is returned is actually just a numerical value, not a list.  r610 does plot.  (Which I don't think it would do if it evaluated to lists.)

Comment: When I evaluate r610[20], I get 12493.5

Comment: In[827]:= r610[20]

Out[827]= 12493.5

Comment: `ClearAll[r610, v610];

r610[T_?NumericQ] := First@Values[FindRoot[temp[R] == T, {R, 10000}]];

v610[T_?NumericQ] := (5 r610[T])/(200000 + r610[T]);` -- the explanation is in the link I posted earlier, along with the foregoing suggestion.

Comment: `r610` would plot if it evaluated to a list. Try it: `ff[x_] := {x^2};
Plot[ff[x], {x, -1, 2}]`.  Your `[[1]]` was formatted as a link in the initial post. It didn't copy properly, if the part 1 was what was intended.

Comment: I tried the ?NumericQ in the v610 definition, that didn't work, but I then tried it the r610 definition, as you actually posted, and that did work.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!